# Why did my Command + V (to paste) suddenly stop working?

Tags: keyboard, macos, copy-paste

Maybe I should be weary every time I do one of these shady Apple updates on my 3-year old Mac running 10.11.5.

Suddenly, the shortcut to paste, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>, stopped working for me. But all other shortcuts using the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key still work, such as *Copy, Cut, Find, Minimize*, etc. *Paste* still works if I do it manually with the mouse by going up to *Edit* and clicking *Paste*.

Even when I log into another user, same problem.  And when I am in Recovery Mode, same problem.  And I don't think I have any recent add-ons, as far as I can tell.

I restarted several times and reset my Keyboard in System Preferences. I even tried a few random code stuff in Monitor that I found on other forums. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Mac Excel 2011 I am still using.

- Right click on the Paste icon in toolbar, choose Properties...
- Next screen, click Keyboard... on right hand side
- In "Press new shortcut key", add command+v.

That worked, even though <kbd>Cmd-V</kbd> was already in list of current keyboard keys for Paste function.

Comment: What is the "paste icon in the toolbar"?

Answer (score 1):

So all of the above unfortunately didn't work for me. If the problem still exists after you've tried it what might help for you is resetting the System Management Controller by pressing `shift + control + option + power button` for a few seconds and then releasing it.

More info on this on [apple's support website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Answer (score 1):

I found that under System Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts, App Shortcuts, I had 'Paste and Match Style' selected for ⌘ + V. I don't recall doing this but maybe I just forgot. This should have been a valid option but instead of pasting and matching the style, the result was it didn't paste anything.

Answer (score -2):

Turn off "Reopen windows when logging in" when restarting.
I have had strange things happen with that terrible thing.

Comment: I've used it without issue since its inception.

Comment: Nope.  That didn't work.

Comment: curious.  why would that make a difference?